# How do a mysql trigger after insert or update [close]

Tags: mysql

Sorry to bother you again with my questions. 
I need to create a trigger in mysql to change the rows of a table. 
The idea is the following:

Whenever I create a new task it will automatically create the status.

```
If StartDate = NULL -> status = Planning 
If have endDate -> status =completed 
If Have StartDate -> status =In Progress 
If current date > dateBeginPrevision ->status = Overdue
```

Does anyone could help me please?

I dont I ask to hear the trigger, only that would give me a little help to get there, because I am a noob in mysql.

Thank you all very much.

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `idTask` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `descTask` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateBeginPrevision` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startDate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endDate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Priority` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTask`)
 )
```

----------EDIT--------------

After this comment: "I dont think you should use trigger here, because trigger is a monitor of table, when the source table has some changes on it (insert, delete ,update)"

I chose to do this kind of checking through the java language, ie directly in my application without relying on the capabilities of the database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should use trigger here, because trigger is a monitor of table, when the source table has some changes on it (insert, delete ,update), it would invoke the trigger on it, and now ,what's your source table?

Comment: Thanks. What do you think I should do?